# Having only 1 Primary Contact

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to limit an Account to have only one Primary Contact (with a small twist).

What I would like to do is, If Contact A is already Primary, and a user goes in selects Contact B as Primary, then I want to have Contact B as Primary, and no longer have Contact A as Primary.

How could I go about doing that?

I have this following code:

```
trigger checkaccount on contact(before insert, before update){

    List<Id> accID = new List<Id>();
    for(contact c : trigger.new){
        if(c.accountId != null){
            accID.add(c.accountId);
        }
    }

    List<account> acc = [select id, (select id, Primary__c from contacts where Primary__c = true) from Account WHERE Id In: accID];
 Map<id, boolean> bool = new map<id,boolean>();
    for(account a : acc){
        bool.put(a.id, a.contacts.size()>0 ? true : false);
    }

    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(bool.get(c.AccountId) == true){
            c.addError('no more primary fields');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try to put your logic in the code?

Comment: In the code above? No I am not a code myself, I found the code above and just altered a little bit of it.  The code above gives works well in the sense that it gives an error when someone tries to select a second primary contact, but it a lot of steps to uncheck Primary contact then select another one..

Comment: so, it will be best time to practice and learn coding... go through trailheads

Comment: That's part of the plan...signed up for David Liu's course on Pluralsight..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Flow and Process builder]I did a quick test with the assumption that all the contacts with the primary flag will be unchecked except the newly updated record with the below approach:

1. Create a flow  with Type = Autolaunched Flow

   - Define two variables varAccountId and
     varNewContactId   with input/output type = input
   - Drag and drop update record
   - Give name Update
     PC
   - Under Filter and Assignment section
   - Update = Contact that meets the following criteria
   - Field
   - i.   AccountId equals varAccountId
   - ii.  Id not equals varNewContactId
   - iii. Primary__c equals true
   - Under Update records fields with variables, constant, input or other values
   - i.  Field: Primary__c   value: {!$GlobalConstant.False}

     2. Set it as start element, Save the flow and activate
     3. Create a process flow with the condition Primary__c equals true and Primary__c ischanged equals true

        - a.    Immediate Action
        - b.    Action
          Type = Flows
        - c.    Select the flow you defined
        - d.    Under set variables
          section
        - i.    AccountId Reference [Contact].AccountId
        - ii.   Id Reference
          [Contact].Id
     4. Save and Activate
     5. Enjoy the coding and test class free world!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!! My only concern is if there's a mass update on the primary field would process builder be able to handle it?

Comment: Sorry, no prior experience with bulk update behavior. Hopefully it should work. You may want to test it out in your full sandbox to see how it works.